# Why params in HTTP POST methods are usually passed in a nested manner

Tags: rest, http

I'm using Rails but this should be irrelevant to framework / language .

I noticed in almost all materials, the POST/PUT/PATCH params are usually passed not at the top level of the body, but in a nested fashion. For example to create an event, it would be

```
body: {
   event: {
      date: ...,
      user_id: ...,
      activities: [...]
   }
}
```

instead of

```
   body: {
      date: ...,
      user_id: ...,
      activities: [...]
   }
```

any particular reason why it's often designed that way?